# Why is a control not initializing? In one Form with two classes

Tags: vb.net, forms

I try to edit my text until it is compare able for others. Many tasks have
not lead to be recoginzeable. First of all i still work not more than with two classes. And my main language i use is not english.
Class one, Form1 holds :

```
Class Form1

Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()

End Sub

End Class
```

Class two, can be named other than class Form1, named Second_Class holds :

```
Class Second_Class
'Dim MainForm As New Form1 'object
WithEvents Button1 As New Button
Public Sub New()
    Development()
End Sub

Sub Development()
    Button1 = New Button With {
        .Size = New Size(40, 40),
        .Location = New Point(30, 30),
        .Text = "Click me"
    }
    Form1.Controls.Add(Button1)
End Sub
End Class
```

By pressing the start without debugger key, the solution can also be achieved with the ctrl + F5 key, a form is starting. But the form starts without a button.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I have tried several possibilities but inheriting and deriving seems to have other visual basic language causes with a control than only working with a console.

Comment: Could you be clearer? What happens when you start the program? What would you like to happen instead?

Comment: `Public Source_Gathering As New Second_Class` You have given Source_Gathering a type but have not created an instance. You need the New keyword.

Comment: To change my above code, class Form1, by adding the New Keyword is not enough. In my Visual Studio Version 'Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019
Version 16.11.8' no Form with a Button is loaded, visible.

Answer (score 0):

It is not easy to recognize the shortest way to write code that has to be maintained.
A tension like summaries are personal logs in relation to others. A cloud at night is not visible inside a building. Less reflections. The english word neat is also a consideration for some who have written the language VB dot Net. Building a heap starts with leaves and a tab in visual studio is not an other side of a leave. Also a second tab.
A Form1 Class Tab for using a second class control has

```
Public Class Form1
Dim FairWay As New MyLabel
Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    FairWay.Application(FairWay.Bunker)
    Controls.Add(FairWay.Bunker)
End Sub
End Class
```

and a MyLabel Class Tab has

```
Public Class MyLabel
Inherits Label
Public WithEvents Bunker As New Label
Sub Application(MudSteel As Label)
    With MudSteel
        .Location = New Point(50, 50)
        .BackColor = Color.Gold
        .Size = New Size(250, 250)
    End With
End Sub
End Class
```